# ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «' postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hola tengo el siguiente problema estoy intentando crear una vista en postgresql

esta es mi instrucción:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cat_ejemplo_view AS 
 SELECT CCC.c_campo1 as id_campo1, CCC.c_campo2 as descripcion
   FROM dblink('host=pruebas dbname=baseprueba user=admin password=admin'::text,
               'select CCC.c_campo1, CCC.c_campo2 from  catalogo_tabla CCC 
                WHERE CCC.c_campo1 LIKE '%000000' AND CCC.c_campo2 != '' AND CCC.version = 3
                order by c_campo1 '::text)
    CCC(c_campo1 character varying(7), c_campo2 character varying(200))
  ORDER BY ccc.c_campo1;
```

Cuando la ejecuto me marca error de sintaxis en el LIKE '%000000`'` si ejecuto la consulta unicamente si me recupera la información el problema es para crear una vista con esa consulta.

Estoy usando la versión 9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por fin lo pude solucionar también me llego a salir el siguiente error ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near postgresql  y esto es por que se tiene que poner apóstrofe doble en las condiciones `=''''` lo cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cat_ejemplo_view AS 
 SELECT CCC.c_campo1 as id_campo1, CCC.c_campo2 as descripcion
   FROM dblink('host=pruebas dbname=baseprueba user=admin password=admin'::text,
               'select CCC.c_campo1, CCC.c_campo2 from  catalogo_tabla CCC 
                WHERE CCC.c_campo1 LIKE ''%000000'' AND CCC.c_campo2 != '''' AND CCC.version = 3
                order by c_campo1 '::text)
    CCC(c_campo1 character varying(7), c_campo2 character varying(200))
  ORDER BY ccc.c_campo1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sobra un apóstrofe en el principio de la cuarta línea, quedaría así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cat_ejemplo_view AS 
 SELECT CCC.c_campo1 as id_campo1, CCC.c_campo2 as descripcion
   FROM dblink('host=pruebas dbname=baseprueba user=admin password=admin'::text,
               select CCC.c_campo1, CCC.c_campo2 from  catalogo_tabla CCC 
               WHERE CCC.c_campo1 LIKE '%000000' AND CCC.c_campo2 != '' AND CCC.version = 3
               order by c_campo1 '::text)
    CCC(c_campo1 character varying(7), c_campo2 character varying(200))
  ORDER BY ccc.c_campo1;
```

Comment: Si le quito el apostrofe marca el error en esa linea